# Direct Incoming Emails to CPanel email server?

Tags: email, dns, exchange-server, cpanel

I've configured several email addresses using the built-in CPanel email utility, and they're all able to successfully send outgoing mail. Incoming mail however is bounced back, with one of the following two errors:

```
Address not found:
The response from the remote server was:
550 5.1.1 <email@domain.com> Recipient not found.

Message not delivered:
The response from the remote server was:
550 5.4.1 [nathan@fortunesfavored.com]: Recipient address rejected: Access denied
```

I believe that these error codes (550 5.4.1 and 550 5.1.1) are Exchange server errors, meaning that incoming mail is being directed to the wrong server. (I'm hosting on a GoDaddy service). Is that correct? If so, is this an issue that I would solve in my DNS settings under the MX entry? Here's what I have now:

```
Priority  Host   Points to                    TTL
10        @      mailstore1.secureserver.net  1 Hour    
0         @      smtp.secureserver.net        1 Hour
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you have to edit your MX entries.

Login to you cpanel account.
under emails click on MX entries.

if there is no MX entry then add a MX entry.

mail.yourdomainname.com and set priority 10